# JBAS015052: Did not receive a response to the deployment operation within the allowed timeout period

Tags: jboss7.x

I am migrating an application from JBOSS 4 to JBOSSAS 7. I followed the guide for migration, converted all the ejbs to ejb3 fixed the JNDI names. After I deploy the ear I see message that the EJBs are bound. After that it goes in a wait state and then just times out with this message:

> JBAS015052: Did not receive a response to the deployment operation within the allowed timeout period [1200 seconds]. Check the server configuration file and the server logs to find more about the status of the deployment.

I turned on the logging to DEBUG, which gives me a few exceptions about Transaction and NIO etc (which after spending a lot of time in JBOSS message groups and this one, I found were harmless).

I don't know how to debug this. I got the stack dump of the process but all I see is that the deployment scanner was waiting on something. Not sure what :

> "DeploymentScanner-threads - 2" prio=5 tid=0000000003d77400 nid=0xb6447000 in Object.wait() [00000000b6446000]
>      java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)

Anyone know how to debug this ? I am pretty damm fraustrated at this point. I mean if it doesn't throw an error, how am I supposed to debug this ?

Answer (score 18):

It is an old post but, if some of you have a similar problem, you can try increasing the `deployment-timeout` in your `standalone.xml`,

1. Find This block

   ```
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:deployment-scanner:1.1">
        <deployment-scanner path="deployments"
            relative-to="jboss.server.base.dir"
            scan-interval="5000" />
    </subsystem>
   ```
2. Then add the attribute `deployment-timeout` (in seconds) to a value (like 20 minutes)

   ```
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:deployment-scanner:1.1">
        <deployment-scanner path="deployments" relative-to="jboss.server.base.dir"
            scan-interval="5000" deployment-timeout="1200"/>
    </subsystem>
   ```

look this for reference

[JBAS015052: Did not receive a response to the deployment operation within the allowed timeout period [60 seconds]](http://my-plife.blogspot.com/2012/11/jbas015052.html)

It is a usual problem in overloaded environments.

Comment: please provide a full answer, not just a link.